# DRY in RelayCommand in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

How to avoid this kind of repetition in the RelayCommand part of the code below:

**MainViewModel.cs**

```
public class MainViewModel : BaseViewModel
{
    public RelayCommand HomeViewCommand { get; set; }
    public RelayCommand CustodyViewCommand { get; set; }
    public RelayCommand OperationsViewCommand { get; set; }

    private BaseViewModel _currentViewModel;
    public BaseViewModel CurrentViewModel
    {
        get => _currentViewModel;
        set
        {
            _currentViewModel = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("CurrentViewModel");
        }
    }
    public MainViewModel()
    {
        CurrentViewModel = new HomeViewModel();
        
        HomeViewCommand = new RelayCommand(o =>
        {
            CurrentViewModel = new HomeViewModel();
        });
        
        CustodyViewCommand = new RelayCommand(o =>
        {
            CurrentViewModel = new CustodyViewModel(); ;
        });
        
        OperationsViewCommand = new RelayCommand(o =>
        {
            CurrentViewModel = new OperationsViewModel(); ;
        });
    }
}
```

And then I bind the Commands to the Buttons...

**MainWindow.xaml**

```
<Button Content="Home"
        Command="{Binding HomeViewCommand}"/>
<Button Content="Custody"
        Command="{Binding CustodyViewCommand}"/>
<Button Content="Operations"
        Command="{Binding OperationsViewCommand}"/>
```

I couldn't figure out how to implement a kind of `NavigateToCommand`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply create identifiers for the view models e.g., enum and store each view model in a `Dictionary` with the ID object as key. Then use the key as `CommandParameter` with the button. The command handler can use this key to select the appropriate view from the `Dictionary`. Alternatively select the view models by index. For example a "Next" or "Previous" button could navigate by index.

The following example use an enum as identifier for the view and as key for the `Dictionary`.

**ViewId.cs**

```
public enum ViewId
{
  Default = 0, Home, Custody, Operations
}
```

**MainViewModel.cs**

```
public class MainViewModel : BaseViewModel
{
  public RelayCommand NavigateToCommand 
    => new RelayCommand(ExecuteNavigateToCommand);

  private BaseViewModel _currentViewModel;
  public BaseViewModel CurrentViewModel
  {
    get => _currentViewModel;
    set
    {
      _currentViewModel = value;
      OnPropertyChanged(nameof(this.CurrentViewModel));
    }
  }

  private Dictionary<ViewId, BaseViewModel> Views { get; }

  public MainViewModel()
  {
    this.Views = new Dictionary<ViewId, BaseViewModel>
    {
      { ViewId.Home, new HomeViewModel() },
      { ViewId.Custody, new CustodyViewModel() },
      { ViewId.Operations, new OperationsViewModel() }     
    };
  }

  private void ExecuteNavigateToCommand(object commadParameter)
  {
    if (commandParameter is ViewId viewId 
      && this.Views.TryGetValue(viewId, out BaseViewModel view)
    {
      this.CurrentViewModel = view;
    }
  }
}
```

**View.xaml**

```
<Button Content="Home" 
        Command="{Binding NavigateToCommand}" 
        CommandParameter="{x:Static ViewId.Home}" />
<Button Content="Custody" 
        Command="{Binding NavigateToCommand}" 
        CommandParameter="{x:Static ViewId.Custody}" />
<Button Content="Operations" 
        Command="{Binding NavigateToCommand}" 
        CommandParameter="{x:Static ViewId.Operations}" />
```